# Creating multiple 'pages' on one sheet of paper

Tags: minipage

It might be an odd question ask, especially in terms of the terminology I'm using, but is it possible to put multiple 'pages' onto a single sheet of paper (eg letter or A4)? It's important that the little pages have page numbers so that pages can reference each other. Also, a page border would be useful though that might be straight forward to do once the pages have been set up. The image below shows a single sheet of paper with multiple pages on it, in this case, six. The mini pages should be bona fide pages so that whatever one can do with a page it can done with one of these mini pages.

One other thing, the little pages shouldn't be zoomed out versions of a larger page, ie the font should be normal 10,11,12pt fonts one finds in a full page. Can this be done without using pdfpages?

[image: g]

Comment: `pdfpages` is the way to do it, but you can use `pgfpages` if you really want to. I wouldn't recommend it over `pdfpages`, but it works well enough as far as I've tried.

Comment: IMO, @cfr suggestion does not completly solve the question, as the use of `pgfpages` or `pdfpages` would involve rezising of the pages and hence rescale the font too. Perhaps using alsso `extsize` could fix this (not tested).

Comment: This is exactly what pgfpages is designed for.  And if you get the initial page size right then it doesn't involve scaling.

Comment: @Jhor What Loop Space says ^^.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can this be done without using pdfpages?

Yes

[image: mwe]

The mini pages (`foo.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9cm,paperheight=8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Lore ipsum}\lipsum[1][1-6]
\section{Nam dui}\lipsum[2][1-6]
\section{Nulla malesuda}\lipsum[3][1-9]
\section{Quisque ullamcorper}\lipsum[4][1-11]
\section{Fusce mauris}\lipsum[5][1-9]
\section{Suspendise vel felis}\lipsum[6][1-8]
\end{document}
```

The multipage (`whatever.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\centering\parskip1em
\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=1]{foo.pdf}}\quad
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=2]{foo.pdf}}\par
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=3]{foo.pdf}}\quad
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=4]{foo.pdf}}\par
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=5]{foo.pdf}}\quad
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=6]{foo.pdf}}\par
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

My answer is too long to give here. However I wrote about this in one of my TUGboat *Glisterings* columns describing various methods of putting a set of small pages onto a single large page. The 7 page column is available at https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99glister.pdf

Comment: These are great layouts!  I might add some of these to `pgfmorepages`.

Comment: @LoopSpace Thank you, I hadn't tried `pgfmorepages`. I'll be interested to see what you come up with.

Answer (score 2):

[`pgfpages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfpages) (and its extension [`pgfmorepages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfmorepages)) has a layout `6 on 1` predefined.

The code below uses `pgfmorepages` because that has an easy way to add borders to pages.  By setting the original geometry to landscape a6, the resulting pages are not scaled when they are put in the larger a4 document.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514680/86}

\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\pgfmorepagesloadextralayouts

\pgfpagesuselayout{6 on 1}[a4paper,border code=\pgfusepath{draw}]

\begin{document}
\Huge

\vspace*{\fill}
\centerline{1}
\vspace*{\fill}

\newpage

\vspace*{\fill}
\centerline{2}
\vspace*{\fill}

\newpage

\vspace*{\fill}
\centerline{3}
\vspace*{\fill}

\newpage

\vspace*{\fill}
\centerline{4}
\vspace*{\fill}

\newpage

\vspace*{\fill}
\centerline{5}
\vspace*{\fill}

\newpage

\vspace*{\fill}
\centerline{6}
\vspace*{\fill}


\end{document}
```